# Get value of dropdown in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I write a click event in jQuery that will capture the value of a dropdown?  I have:

```
var select = $('select #dealerName');
    $(function {
        select.click(function {
            alert( $('#dealerName').val() );
        });

    });
```

I'm just trying to get the value -- that's why I'm alerting it.  What would the click function look like?  The id on my dropdown is "dealerName".  The above is not alerting anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're not selecting it correctly

```
var select = $('select #dealerName');
```

should be

```
var select = $('select#dealerName');
```

BUT... I'm assuming you want to get the value after it is selected? as it stands as soon as you open the dropdown you will get an alert.

Instead of using `.click()` , use `.change()`

**EDIT :**  Personally I would just attach the handler directly on the object.

```
$('select#dealerName').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: That doesn't alert anything.  How can I test to see if jquery is being called at all?

Comment: Also your function call looks funky: $(function () {

Answer (score 1):

Five things:

1. Unless your javascript code is at the bottom of the document, you need to include *all* your jQuery inside $(function() { }); - as it is right now it will try to find your select before the DOM is ready to be accessed.
2. If the ID of the `<select>` element is `#dealerName`, your jQuery selector is going to be $('#dealerName') - as it is right now you are looking for a descendant to a `<select>` with the ID specified. You also don't want to do select#dealerName as IDs are meant to be unique and specifiying the tag is only going to slow jQuery down.
3. `click` will fire as soon as someone clicks on the select as opposed to when a new option is chosen. You probably want `change`
4. Not too big of a deal, but there is a slightly popular convention to name variables that refer to jQuery wrappers with a `$` at the beginning to be able to quickly tell what is a jQuery wrapped.
5. Inside an event call you can quickly reference the element in question with `this`

So a working example would be:

```
$(function() {
   $('#dealerName').change(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I see a few possible errors:

Remove the space in the first line selector.

```
select#dealername
```

That means "the select tag with an id of dealername." Your version is "the element called dealername that is a *child* of a select tag".

Also, when writing inline functions, put () after the `function` keyword.